# Issue making header file for custom message

Tags: ros, rosserial-client

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good evening partners

First of all I want to apologise beacuse this is a similar question to this one I solved time ago:
http://answers.ros.org/question/119031/rosserial_client-does-not-include-make_librarypy/

I have started the tutorial on a new Raspberry of my students´s group. We followed all steps. We found the same issue that in the question I asked wich it´s mencioned above:

> I'm given : [rosrun] Couldn't find executable named make_library.py below /home/pi/catkin_ws/install/share/rosserial_client.

To solve it I did the same that time ago:

EDIT 1(from the other post) : I have done the next

cp -r ~/catkin_ws/src/rosserial/rosserial_client/src/rosserial_client/ /catkin_ws/install/share/rosserial_client/src/

Then I was able to call " rosrun rosserial_client make_library.py ~/sketchbook/libraries My_Msgs_Package" and create the header file but now when I type the call from above it seems that make_library.py does nothing beacuse it does not create the header file for My_Msgs_Package

What´s worng ? Can you help me please?

Thanks you so much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/129161/issue-making-header-file-for-custom-message/) by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2014-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In groovy/hydro, things were updated so that A) each client has it's own make_libraries.py script (for instance rosserial_adruino is different from rosserial_embedded_linux, this allows us to set things like endianness and whether the platform supports Float64) B) all messages are generated at once for every package on your path. Therefore, you need to run:

```
rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py <sketckbook_output_folder>
```

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on 2014-02-16**:
Thanks you so much for answering. It works fine.

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-08-03**:
I have the same problem. Please tell me whether I m doign right or not.
Once I create the new msg folder in my package, should I delete the old ros_lib in the sketchbook and run the above command again? Am I right?
Regards